# When crawling with Scrapy, can I rely on requests having referer headers?

Tags: python, http, header, request, scrapy

I'm crawling a website and saving the url of the page that links to each page in 'Page' item fields, in order to reconstruct the site tree later. An easy way to do this is to access response.request.headers['referer'], which is the referer header for the request. Is this header actually reliable - i.e. will it always be there for requests generated by Scrapy, or is it possible for it not to be accurate / not exist for a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a [`RefererMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=referer#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.referer) *enabled by default*:

> Populates Request Referer header, based on the URL of the Response which generated it.

FYI, here is [the implementation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e748ca50ca3e83ac703e02538a27236fedd53a7d/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py).